# Apache Start Problem on Windows

Tags: apache

I just installed the apache 2.2 http server and I get this error message whenever I hit start:

[alt text http://img837.imageshack.us/img837/6519/apacheproblem.jpg](http://img837.imageshack.us/img837/6519/apacheproblem.jpg)

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kill whatever is bound to port 80 (might be IIS for example)

Comment: Thanks, in this case the thing was skype's client.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem with Sykpe. For any others reading this, this [Skype support item](https://support.skype.com/en-gb/faq/FA528/Conflicts-with-applications-such-as-Apache-or-IIS-working-on-port-80-443) details how to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

you might have IIS running. and it runs as a service and starts each time you start windows.
open Run type this and press ENTER key:
services.msc

the Services console will open.
now look for IIS(internet information services) service and open its properties and change its start-up mode to Manual from the dropdownbox. plus stop the service to free the port number 80 for Apache to use.

take a look at this link: [Starting and Stopping IIS](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windowsserver2003/library/iis/95826e7a-bac4-4e1f-bcb6-c52d49c9d7f4.mspx)

I hope this helps.